# Alignment with an empty argument

Tags: environments, alignment, arguments

Here is a little newcommand exo with one argument (for a title for example).

Without this argument, the alignment is bad.

Is it possible to improve this[image] ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{counter}

\newenvironment{exo}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{counter} 
   \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left, trim right = (dot), baseline]
   \coordinate (dot) at (0,0) ;
   \node[minimum size = 5mm,
         rounded corners = 1mm, 
         fill = blue!20,
         align = center,
         left = 5mm, 
         anchor = base east] (foo) {\thecounter} ;
   \end{tikzpicture}%
   {\bfseries #1}%
   }%
   {}
   

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

%%
\begin{exo}{Un titre}

\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}
%%

\medskip

%%
\begin{exo}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}
%%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is:

```
\begin{exo}{Un titre}

\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}
```

the text "Un titre" is printed in bold, then the space (from the end of the first line). The second line is empty and generates `\par`, i.e. the text "Un titre" is finalized as the first paragraph. Next paragraph is started by the text `\lipsum[2]` without indentation. If you remove the empty line here:

```
\begin{exo}{Un titre}
\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}
```

you get bold "Un titre", next the **space** from the end of the line and the next text from `\lipsum[2]` follows this space at the same line. This is, IMHO, desired behavior.

Your second example:

```
\begin{exo}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}
```

creates no bold text, then inserts the space from the end of the line and then the text `\lipsum[2]` follows. You can disable this space by adding `%` at the end of the line:

```
\begin{exo}{}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}
```

or you can add the test to your macro "if the parameter is empty then ignore spaces":

```
\newenvironment{exo}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{counter} 
   \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left, trim right = (dot), baseline]
   \coordinate (dot) at (0,0) ;
   \node[minimum size = 5mm,
         rounded corners = 1mm, 
         fill = blue!20,
         align = center,
         left = 5mm, 
         anchor = base east] (foo) {\thecounter} ;
   \end{tikzpicture}%
   {\bfseries #1}%
   \ifx^#1^\ignorespaces\fi   %%% <- this line is added
   }%
   {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd make the title an optional argument, and add vertical spacing above and below such environment.

Since you appear to want the title on a line by itself, using `\par\nopagebreak` will do the job without having to add a blank line at the start of the environment's text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{counter}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exo}{o}{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \refstepcounter{counter}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left, trim right = (dot), baseline]
    \coordinate (dot) at (0,0) ;
    \node[
      minimum size = 5mm,
      rounded corners = 1mm, 
      fill = blue!20,
      align = center,
      left = 5mm, 
      anchor = base east
     ] {\thecounter} ;
   \end{tikzpicture}%
   \IfValueT{#1}{\textbf{#1}\par\nopagebreak}%
   \ignorespaces
}%
{\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{exo}[Un titre]
\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}
\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed the name `foo` from the node, as it serves no purpose.